Can I have a NavLink with a relative URL
I have a WebAssembly Blazor app and I want the URLs in my menu to be relative to the current path.
If I navigate to /demo/ and I click on a link with an href of games, I want it to navigate to /demo/games but instead, it treats the href as being absolute and navigates to /games.
Is there any way to achieve this. I don't want to have string fields for every link in the menu so that I can prefix every one with /demo/ individually in code.

Are you using a base tag in your head?

@mxmissile That's it - The template put it into the index.html; I hadn't seen it there.

You can add a <base> tag in your html head, which should give you control over the url's prefix:
<head>
  <base href="/demo/" />
  ...
</head>

